# How to read trained file to FaceRecognitionEngine object in OpenImaj

Tags: java, openimaj

I am using OpenImaj for face recognition. Due to the long time it takes train the data at runtime, I am saving the already trained data to system to use it later.

I am using the below code to save the trained data

```java
IOUtils.writeToFile(faceEngine, new File("traineddata.txt"));
```

Please how do I read the data back to the faceEngine object when the software loads?

The faceEngine object is created this way

```java
FKEFaceDetector faceDetector = new FKEFaceDetector(new HaarCascadeDetector(40));`
EigenFaceRecogniser<KEDetectedFace, Person> faceRecogniser = EigenFaceRecogniser.create(20, new RotateScaleAligner(), 1, DoubleFVComparison.CORRELATION, 0.9f);
FaceRecognitionEngine<KEDetectedFace, Person> faceEngine = FaceRecognitionEngine.create(faceDetector, faceRecogniser);
```

How do I load the `traineddata.txt` file?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to load the `FaceRecognitionEngine<KEDetectedFace, Person>`  object again with `IOutils.readFromFile`.

(see http://openimaj.org/apidocs/src-html/org/openimaj/io/IOUtils.html#line.1071)

Comment: How do I pass the file to the faceEngine object because I tried `faceEngine.readBinary(IOUtils.readFromFile(traineddata));` and I am getting some errors WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.AccessClassLoader (file:/C:/Users/Emperor/.m2/repository/com/esotericsoftware/kryo/kryo/2.21/kryo-2.21.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.AccessClassLoader

Comment: @Emperor From my understanding of javadoc it should be `FaceRecognitionEngine<KEDetectedFace, Person> faceEngine = IOUtils.readFromFile(new File("traineddata.txt"));`

Comment: The `traineddata` variable has already been declared before `File traineddata = new File("data/traineddata.txt");`

Comment: My snippet was based on the code you posted above. If in meanwhile you extracted that file reference into a separate variable you need to adjust the code for sure.

Comment: Okay. I did `faceEngine = IOUtils.readFromFile(new File("traineddata.txt"));` and I got error WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.AccessClassLoader (file:/C:/Users/Emperor/.m2/repository/com/esotericsoftware/kryo/kryo/2.21/kryo-2.21.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int)

Comment: So it does not work this way? I'd assume that a warning should not prevent the code from working. Which java version you're using?

Comment: Java 11. I also get an error at the end of the warning `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openimaj.image.processing.face.recognition.FaceRecognitionEngine`